# How to load partial view content and dispose previous partial view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I've just started asp.net MVC programming and have 2 problem with my project.
I have a controller named `DefaultController` and a view named `Register.cshtml`. Also I created 2 partial view named `_AddUser` and `_UserList`. When I run my project, the `_AddUser` partial view shows in `Register.cshtml` and I can insert a new user. (See attached image)

[image]

When I click on `User List` from the right panel, I can see `User List` (`_UserList` partial view is shown) see image below:

[image]

Now I have two problems:
1 - When I press the Ctrl + U, I'm waiting to see `_UserList` partial view page source but I see `_AddUser` partial view page source. Do not `_UserList` partial view properly loaded? how can I load it correctly?

2 - the second problem: I want to reset all field and controls in `_AddUser` partial view after success inserted. how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

1) Presumably you are loading your partials with ajax calls. The page source only reflects the html which was initially loaded,  not changes subsequently made dynamically.

2) After a successful call to AddUser,  redirect to the AddUser action using RedirectToAction. This will effectively reset the page.